# Moving a Portal instance from the Sandbox to Production

Tags: portal

I have a fully functioning Sandbox in which I am upgrading a making changes to the portal instance. After all testing is done, What is the process of moving the sandbox portal to production?

Comment: The answer to your question depends a lot on your preferences and several other things like do you have Eclipse available to you? Is your portal considered an "Application"? What exactly have you modified during your "upgrade"?

Comment: Hi Jessica, can you please elaborate what do you mean by moving the sandbox portal to production?are you try to deploy the changes that you might changed in your sandbox org like adding vf page on the portal.or adding crud permission for object.please Clarify?